# Grouping by adding two BigDecimal type attributes of a class

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want sum of two BigDecimal type attributes of the same class and grouping them with some other attribute of the class.

I tried using Collectors.groupingBy() and Collectors.reducing() method but this is applicable for only one attribute that can be summed up.

Employee class has below attributes:

```
class Employee{
 private String name;
 private BigDecimal salary;
 private BigDecimal bonus;
 private String department;

 // Getters and Setters
 }

employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                              Employee::getDepartment, Collectors.reducing(
                                        BigDecimal.ZERO, 
                    (id, emp) -> id.add(emp.getSalary().add(emp.getBonus)), 
                                         BigDecimal::add)));
```

As per the last piece of the code, Collectors.reducing() I want sum of Salary and Bonus that will be grouped along with the respective departments. For example,

Department A -

Employee 1- Salary 1000, Bonus 100

Employee 2- Salary 2000, Bonus 100

Department B -

Employee 3 - Salary 5000, Bonus 100

Now I want a map like below:

[Department-A, 3200],[Department-b, 5100]

Comment: try this `employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Employee::getDepartment, Collectors.reducing(
                        BigDecimal.ZERO,
                        Employee::getSum,
                        BigDecimal::add)));` and define a method such `BigDecimal getSum(){
        return this.bonus.add(this.salary);
    }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve that effect, you need to combine two separate `Collectors`: groupingBy() and reducing():

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> result = employeeList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors
        .groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, Collectors
          .reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, e -> e.getBonus().add(e.getSalary()), BigDecimal::add)));
```

output:
    `{DepartmentB=5100, DepartmentA=3200}`

Comment: In other words, the OP was using a `BiFunction` like function for the `mapper`  to `reducing` whereas it should have been a `Function` i.e. `e -> ....` instead of `(e, a) -> ...` as your answer illustrates.

Answer (score 4):

First define a method like this:

```
 public BigDecimal getSumOfBonusAndSarary(){
    return this.bonus.add(this.salary);
}
```

then use

```
employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Employee::getDepartment, Collectors.reducing(
                    BigDecimal.ZERO,
                    Employee::getSumOfBonusAndSarary,
                    BigDecimal::add)));
```

or even use `toMap()`

```
 employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getDepartment,
                                      Employee::getSumOfBonusAndSarary,BigDecimal::add))
```

Comment: I like the use of `Collectors.toMap` :)

Comment: Actually I don't want to change the class. I used below code its working as of now:

Comment: Map<String, BigDecimal> depatMaps = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(em -> em.getDepartment(), 
       Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, emp -> emp.getBonus().add(emp.getSalary()), BigDecimal::add)));

Comment: The toMap() approach also looks good, I used below without changing the class and its working fine:

employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors
    .toMap(emp -> emp.getDepartment(), em -> em.getBonus().add(em.getSalary()), BigDecimal::add));

Comment: I added that method just for simplify.